# Getting a C pointer to a function generated by Theano?

Tags: python, numpy, ffi, theano, python-cffi

I would like to use a Theano function from C/Fortran code (in particular, I want to use an implicit ODE solver written in Fortran with a function created in Theano). Are there any examples/resources on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged your question with ffi/cffi but that's for calling foreign code from Python. However it sounds like you actually want to call Python/Theano code from C/Fortran. For that, the documentation on [Embedding Python in Another Application](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html) might be helpful.

In principle you could just run Theano Python code from your C/Fortran code via facilities in `Python.h`.

Although Theano compiles some operations via C code, I don't believe it produces an natively executable function/library for the entire computation graph that could then be linked in by some other, non-Python, application.

Update: via the [thread on the Theano mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-users/0hl6O8f260U)... apparently [a prototype for having Theano create a linkable library](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/1408#issuecomment-106029111) was done some time ago but isn't currently integrated into Theano.

Comment: Fwiw, CFFI can be used to call Python code from C, too, using callbacks.  (No idea about the context, so I don't know if this comment helps.)